# WebAssembly: Standardized Interfaces

Tags: protocols, webassembly

The way WebAssembly interfaces with the external world is quite elegant and secure. Adding a function interface is easy, but not yet standardized.

Have calling conventions been established already for Javascript environments (mostly for accessing the DOM in the Browser or the filesystem in Node)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventions for manipulating DOM nodes or using external APIs have not been created yet, but a couple of the WebAssembly proposals / future features will support this.

The first is [the reference types proposal](https://github.com/WebAssembly/reference-types), which allows extends the type system, adding a new `anyref` type that allows modules to hold references to objects provided by the host environment, i.e. you can pass a JS object to your wasm module.

The second is the [host bindings](https://github.com/WebAssembly/host-bindings) proposal that allows WebAssembly modules to create, pass around, call, and manipulate JavaScript / DOM objects. It adds a number host bindings section that includes annotations that describes binding mechanism / interface that should be constructed.

Rust already has a tool, [wasm-bindgen](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/04/javascript-to-rust-and-back-again-a-wasm-bindgen-tale/), that is very similar in purpose and closely aligns with this proposal. With wasm-bindgen you can pass objects such as strings across the wasm / JS boundary with ease. The tool adds the binding metadata to the wasm module, and generates the required JS glue code.